# Clicking One Button Effecting All

Tags: android, android-imagebutton

So, I have this android app that is supposibly a board game. It has multiple buttons on it, and when selected, I want the selected one to gain a boarder. But, for some reason, when pressing one, it selectes everything or just doesn't deselect. What am I forgetting to do or doing wrong? Because logically, it shouldn't change anything other than that tile. Their is no For loop with setImageBitmap!

onClickListener:

```
//set onCLickListener on each tile
public void setOnClickListenerOnTile(TileClass tileI){
    ImageButton tile = (ImageButton) findViewById (tileI.getId());
    tile.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener (){
        @Override
        public void onClick (View V){
            Log.i(TAG, "tileOnClick");
            ImageButton tile = (ImageButton) findViewById (V.getId());

            /*Following code checks if...
             *1. if no tile is selected
             *2. if the tile that is clicked is also the one that is selected
             *3. if the tile selected is different than the one that is clicked*/
            //if 1. happens, then add boarder
            if (selectedTile == 0){
                Log.i(TAG, "First Choice: 1");
                //set tile with boarder
                tile.setImageBitmap(modifyTile(1,color.blue, mapTile[findTileById(tile.getId(), mapTile)].tilePic));
                //remember what tile is selected
                selectedTile = V.getId();
            }
            //else if 2. happens, then remove boarder
            else if (selectedTile == V.getId()){
                Log.i(TAG, "First Choice: 2");
                //set tile without boarder
                tile.setImageBitmap(mapTile[findTileById(tile.getId(), mapTile)].tilePic);
                tile.setImageBitmap(blankTileBitmap);
                tile.refreshDrawableState();
                //remember what tile is selected
                selectedTile = 0;
            }
            //else if 3. happens, then remove the boarder on the selectedTile and add boarder on the clickedTile
            else if (selectedTile != V.getId() && selectedTile != 0){
                Log.i(TAG, "First Choice: 3");
                //remove old boarder
                ImageButton tempIB = (ImageButton) findViewById (selectedTile);
                tempIB.setImageBitmap(mapTile[findTileById(selectedTile, mapTile)].tilePic);
                //add new boarder
                tile.setImageBitmap(modifyTile(1,color.blue, mapTile[findTileById(tile.getId(), mapTile)].tilePic));
                //remember what tile is selected
                selectedTile = V.getId();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

modifyTile:

```
//Method function:
//to modify a tile
//modificationNum code:
//1: add boarders
//2: remove boarders
//Param: accepts the type of modifications as first parameter, 
//color ID as listed in color resource (not Color),
//and a bitmap of the tile
//
public Bitmap modifyTile (int modificationNum, int color, Bitmap bitmap){
    int count, count2;
    Log.i(TAG, "modifyTile has been called!");
    //first, find out which modification todo
    //if modificationNum == 1,  then it is to add a border
    if (modificationNum == 1){
        if (bitmap == null){
            Log.i(TAG, "null error");
        }
        //set tile boarders on the top
        for (count = 1; count < tileLength; count++){
            bitmap.setPixel(count, 1, getResources().getColor(color));
        }
        //sides...
        for (count = 1; count < (tileLength); count++){
            bitmap.setPixel(1, count, getResources().getColor(color));
            bitmap.setPixel((tileLength - 1), count, getResources().getColor(color));
        }

        //set tile boarders on the bottom
        for (count = 1; count < tileLength; count++){
            bitmap.setPixel(count-1, tileLength-1, getResources().getColor(color));
        }
    }
```

getAllTileId:

```
//get id of every tile (may take a long time) (not done)
public int[] getAllTileId (){
    int count, count2;
    Log.i(TAG, "getAllTileId has been called!");
    //set up variables...
    //have to set up a view for TableLayout so that I can find the tile's id using Tags (it has to be it's childs)
    View v = (TableLayout) findViewById (R.id.mapTable);
    ImageButton imageButton;
    int temp, globalCount;
    int results[] = new int[50];
    for (count = 0, globalCount = 0; count < 9; count++ ){
        if (count % 2 == 0){
            temp = 6;
        }
        else{
            temp = 5;
        }
        for (count2 = 0; count2 < temp; count2++, globalCount++){
            imageButton = (ImageButton) v.findViewWithTag ("land" + (count + 1) + (count2 + 1));

            results[globalCount] =  imageButton.getId();
            Log.i(TAG, "land #" + (count+1) + (count2+1) + "'s id = " + results[globalCount]); 
        }
    }
    Log.i(TAG, "getAllTileId length" + results.length);
    return results;
}
```

findTileById:

```
//find a tile in an array using it's id
public int findTileById (int id, TileClass[] map){
    Log.i(TAG, "findTileById has been called!");
    int count=0;
    for (count = 0; count < map.length && map[count].getId() != id; count++);
    if (count >= map.length){
        Log.i(TAG, "findTileById FAIL");
    }
    return count;
}
```

EDIT:
Here is onCreate:

```
//onCreate
@Override
public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView (R.layout.activity_board);


    //**TEST AREA, DELETE AFTER**

    //**TEST AREA END**

    //get the way to convert from dp to pixels and set up tileLength (in pixels)
    metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    dpToPixels = metrics.density;
    tileLength = (int) Math.ceil(44 * dpToPixels);

    //set tilePic dimensions
    tilePic = new int[tileLength * tileLength];
    Log.i(TAG, "tileLength = " + tileLength + " and dpToPixels = " + dpToPixels);

    //set up colors
    blue = getResources().getColor(R.color.blue);

    //set up blank selected tile bitmap
    selectedTileBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(tileLength, tileLength, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    //set tile boarders
    selectedTileBitmap = modifyTile (1, color.blue, selectedTileBitmap);

    //set up blank tile bitmap
    blankTileBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(tileLength, tileLength, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    for (count = 0; count < tileLength; count++){
        for (count2 = 0; count2 < tileLength; count2++){
            blankTileBitmap.setPixel(count, count2, getResources().getColor(color.white));
        }
    }

    //first... get map tile ids...
    mapTileId = new int [50];
    mapTileId = getAllTileId ();

    //set up mapTile
    mapTile = new TileClass[50];
    for (count = 0; count < 50; count++){

        //first... get the tile (which is an ImageButton)
        tempIB = (ImageButton) findViewById (mapTileId[count]);
        //next step is to create a stringModifier to get the coordinates of the tile through it's tag
        stringModifier = new StringBuilder (tempIB.getTag().toString());
        //create the tile...
        mapTile [count] = new TileClass (tempIB.getId(), Integer.parseInt(stringModifier.substring(4, 5)), Integer.parseInt(stringModifier.substring(5,6)), blankTileBitmap);
        Log.i(TAG, "count = " + count);
        Log.i(TAG, "test count" + mapTile[count].getId());
    }

    //set up all the bitmap of the tiles on screen
    for (count = 0; count < 50; count++){
        tempIB = (ImageButton) findViewById (mapTile [count].getId());
        tempIB.setImageBitmap(mapTile[count].tilePic);
    }

    Log.i(TAG, "Finished setting up mapTile.");
    //get id of every tile

    //set up each tile with an onClick
    for (count = 0; count < 50; count++){
        setOnClickListenerOnTile(mapTile[count]);
    }

}
```

Comment: I suspect `mapTile[x].tilePic` for all `x` reference the same bitmap. When you change one, all of them change. Could you verify this or post your code where you initialize the `mapTile` and its pic.

Comment: Why would it reference all the same bitmap? I set up each part of the array with a different TileClass. Oh, and also, sometimes, if I click a certain button to the right, only that one gets clicked like normal but still doesn't deselect.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found my problem.
The user is able to click a button before onCreate is done, which is also before a lot of the arrays that are used to find / initialize other buttons are initialized. So, when the user clicks the button too fast, the array references to every button.